# Pandas group by and sorting by values within the group

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, ranking

After running XGBoost and getting the prediction, I need to sort the ranks withing the based on group id. I've tried several methods but was unsuccessful.

My data:

```
id     hotel_id   rank
1       5         2
1       3         3
1       4         1
2       23        4
2       12        2
2       62        3
2       22        1
```

This would be the outcome after `group_by` and sorting based on `rank`. It's important that the id remains unchanged.

```
id     hotel_id   rank
1       4         1
1       5         2
1       3         3
2       22        1
2       12        2
2       62        3
2       23        4
```

Comment: df.groupby('id').cumcount()+1

Comment: `df.sort_values(['id','rank'])`?

Comment: That works @QuangHoang thanks. I am probably just titled and not thinking straight.  Can you post your answer so I can approve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is just `sort_values`:

```
df.sort_values(['id','rank'])
```

Output:

```
   id  hotel_id  rank
2   1         4     1
0   1         5     2
1   1         3     3
6   2        22     1
4   2        12     2
5   2        62     3
3   2        23     4
```